# What entries to add to app.yaml to handle expiration of files of a GWT client app?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, app.yaml

[Google give](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging#compiler_options) the following example of setting up an Apache server to serve a GWT app.

What is the equivalent entries to an AppEngine (GAE) app.yaml file?

```
<Files *.nocache.*>
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresDefault "now"
  Header merge Cache-Control "public, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
</Files>

<Files *.cache.*>
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresDefault "now plus 1 year"
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/appconfig#Static_Cache_Expiration

> The expiration time will be sent in the Cache-Control and Expires HTTP
>   response headers, and therefore, the files are likely to be cached by
>   the user's browser, as well as intermediate caching proxy servers such
>   as Internet Service Providers.